# Why i lost this hand?

Tags: straight, holdem

[image: Image from the situation]
Table straight. so tied or do I have higher card? How come I lost? Like my hand was 'a straight, ace high', and I assume, he had the same? What am I missing. This is from Unibet site and I really don't know the rules but can you help me?

Comment: Closing as this is a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Your opponent has a diamond flush (five of the same suit), which beats the straight on the board.

If your opponent did not have two diamonds, the hand would be tied. The King you hold is irrelevant; only your best five cards count towards your hand.

Comment: Thank you. How can i be this blind. I try to keep my eyes open next time. I am really confused.